# How to remove a long space from a string

Tags: stata

I have a string variable in my dataset with a large space and I am not sure how i can remove it.

I have already tried:

```
replace x = subinstr(x," ", "", .)
```

However, nothing happened.

Below you can find an example of the string:

> Used: An item that has been used previously. The item may have some signs of
>       cosmetic wear, but is fully
>   operational and functions as intended. This item may be a floor model or store return that has been used.

I am trying to convert it to:

> Used: An item that has been used previously. The item may have some signs of cosmetic wear, but is fully operational and functions as intended. This item may be a floor model or store return that has been used. See the seller's listing for full details and description of any imperfections.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer using the check-mark if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to tell Stata to eliminate all spaces that are two characters long or greater.

The following works for me:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate string = "Used: An item that has been used previously. The item may have some signs of cosmetic wear, but is fully" ///
+ "                                                                       operational and functions as intended. This item may be a floor model or store return that has been used."
generate new_string = subinstr(string,"  ", "", .)

list
```

Note that i changed `" "` to `"  "`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than counting the number of space characters, just trim the consecutive internal space characters with `stritrim()`. So,

```
replace x = stritrim(x)
```

If you are still running into issues, there may be other hidden characters lurking in the string. In which case you may want to use something like Nick Cox's [charlist](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s430301.html).